# hover this + after and this (n+1) and before

Tags: css

[jsfiddle.net/rqJAY/](http://jsfiddle.net/rqJAY/)

HTML:

```
<table class="table_database_edit">
<tr><td>Magazyn wycieraczek</td><td>Edytuj</td><td>Usuń</td></tr>
<tr class="more" id=""><td colspan="3">aa</td></tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>Edytuj</td><td>Usuń</td></tr>
<tr class="more" id=""><td colspan="3">aa</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tr.more{
    #display: none;
}
table.table_database_edit{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table.table_database_edit  tr:nth-child(4n+3), table.table_database_edit  tr:nth-child(4n+4){
    background-color: #EFF0F1;
}
table.table_database_edit  tr:hover:nth-child(n) + tr:nth-child(n):after{
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
table.table_database_edit  tr:hover:nth-child(n+1) + tr:nth-child(n+1):before{
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

I have table. Every two rows is a group. The groups alternate background color. Rows 1 and 2 are white. Rows 3 and 4 are gray. Rows 5 and 6 are white. Etc.

I want to set the background-color to yellow when you hover over a group. How I can do it?

Comment: What's `#display: none;` meant to do? CSS comment syntax is `/* comment */`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is `tbody`.  The `tbody` element is similar to `colgroup`, but used for grouping rows.  From there, the CSS is simple:

```
<table class="table_database_edit">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Magazyn wycieraczek</td><td>Edytuj</td><td>Usuń</td></tr>
        <tr class="more" id=""><td colspan="3">aa</td></tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr><td>test</td><td>Edytuj</td><td>Usuń</td></tr>
        <tr class="more" id=""><td colspan="3">aa</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tr.more{
    #display: none;
}
table.table_database_edit{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table.table_database_edit  tbody:nth-child(odd) tr {
    background-color: #EFF0F1;
}

table.table_database_edit  tbody:hover tr {
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rqJAY/13/

Comment: I thought 'tbody' is not akcept with most web browser, because I see in Firefox always add this tag.

Comment: If you don't insert a `tbody` tag, an anonymous one will typically be added by the browser.  I add an implicit `tbody` in most of my tables, since I will style `th` tags differently depending on whether they appear within a `thead`, `tbody`, or `tfoot` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to modify your HTML or use javascript. I thought about this a bit and I think the answer is 'no' due to one reason.

There is no 'previous sibling' selector in CSS. You use `before` and `after` in your example code, but these pseduo-selectors are for inserting content, not for modifying the CSS attributes of siblings.

The closest is the adjacent sibling combinator, but it only selects the next sibling. There is [no previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector) available. So you can highlight both rows when over the first row, but not the first row when over the second.

http://jsfiddle.net/rqJAY/2/

I thought about using classes, but again the lack of a previous sibling combinator spells disaster. Unless you did something like assign a unique class to every single grouping. That would result in a lot of redundant html and css.

You will need to modify your HTML or use javascript. If you can modify the HTML I would abandon the table and use divs instead. If you can use javascript it is relatively trivial to implement.

--edit

I didn't realize you could declare multiple tbody's in a single table. This definitely seems the way to go if you can modify the html.

Comment: This is the same thing I just came up with: not without a previous selector (which doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but here's a solution using jQuery and CSS. This will be a better cross-browser solution as CSS :nth-child isn't supported by all major browsers yet.

jQuery:

```
//Add group classes to rows
$('table.table_database_edit tr').each(function () {
    if ($('.table_database_edit tr').index($(this)) + 1 !== 1 && ($('.table_database_edit tr').index($(this)) + 1) % 4 === 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('groupOne').addClass('groupTwo');
        $(this).prev().removeClass('groupOne').addClass('groupTwo');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('groupOne');
        $(this).next().addClass('groupOne');
    }
});

//Highlight groups of two
$('table.table_database_edit tr').hover(function () {
    if ($('.table_database_edit tr').index($(this)) === 0 || $('.table_database_edit tr').index($(this)) % 2 === 0) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
        $(this).next().addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
        $(this).prev().addClass('highlight');
    }
}, function () {
    $('.table_database_edit tr').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

CSS:

```
table.table_database_edit {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table.table_database_edit tr.groupOne {
    background-color: #fff;
}
table.table_database_edit tr.groupTwo {
    background-color: #EFF0F1;
}
table.table_database_edit tr.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Let me know if you need me to tweak it!

Complete Solution: [Updated JSFiddle - Unlimited Grouping](http://jsfiddle.net/rqJAY/9/)

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct fiddle url? Only one row is highlighting on hover.

Comment: I would like have this efect without JS

Comment: Wasn't sure if he wanted them individually changed on hover or as a group. Updated the answer with 2nd fiddle.

Comment: As group, and for any group.

Comment: Updated answer again to accomodate for correct grouping no matter how many rows exist. I know you'd prefer a non JS solution, but not sure it's possible to create the desired effect with pure CSS. Check out the new fiddle.